# How to change that a function type with no receiver is inferred by default?

Tags: kotlin

Could someone come up with an example to illustrate what it means?

When I was reading Kotlin [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type) about lambda functions, there is a green box that said:

> A function type with no receiver is inferred by default, even if a
> variable is initialized with a reference to an extension function. To
> alter that, specify the variable type explicitly.

FYI, the code below is at the top of the green box, so it should be related to it:

```
val repeatFun: String.(Int) -> String = { times -> this.repeat(times) }
val twoParameters: (String, Int) -> String = repeatFun // OK

fun runTransformation(f: (String, Int) -> String): String {
    return f("hello", 3)
}
val result = runTransformation(repeatFun) // OK
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the short answer:

```kotlin
fun Int.makeHexString(): String = toString(radix = 16)
println(255.makeHexString())) // ✅ correct
val f = Int::makeHexString
println(255.f())) // ❌ compiler error!
```

---

For the longer explanation, let's start with a normal (non-extension) function. Let's say we have a conversion that takes a number and returns a `String`.

```kotlin
fun makeHexString(n: Int): String = n.toString(radix = 16)
println(makeHexString(255)) // ff
```

In Kotlin, we can make a variable that holds a reference to this function. The reference can be invoked in the same way as the original function.

```kotlin
fun makeHexString(n: Int): String = n.toString(radix = 16)
val f = ::makeHexString
println(f(255)) // ff
```

The variable `f` has a type, which is the type of the function it points to. In this case, the function's type is `(Int) -> String`, because it takes a parameter of type `Int` and returns a `String`. The compiler has automatically inferred this type, because we didn't specify it.

If we want, we can rewrite the original function as an extension function.

```kotlin
fun Int.makeHexString(): String = toString(radix = 16)
val hex = 255.makeHexString()
```

The behaviour is the same, but we call the function differently now. The input number appears in the receiver position, instead of in the parameter list.

We can still make a reference to the extension function, if we use a slightly different syntax.

```kotlin
fun Int.makeHexString(): String = toString(radix = 16)
val f = Int::makeHexString
println(255.f())) // ❌ compiler error!
```

But notice that we *can't* invoke the reference in the same way that we invoked the original function. The above code doesn't compile.

The reason is that Kotlin has assumed the function's type is still actually `(Int) -> String`. This is what is being described in the documentation you quoted in your question.

We can fix it by specifying an explicit type for the function. Instead of `(Int) -> String`, we can specify `Int.() -> String`, to indicate that the input should be in the receiver position instead of in the parameter list.

```kotlin
fun Int.makeHexString(): String = toString(radix = 16)
val f: Int.() -> String = Int::makeHexString
println(255.f())
```

Now we can invoke the function reference as an extension, in the same way that we could invoke the original function.

Choosing to make a function into an extension function is a stylistic and ergonomic choice that can make the function easier to implement or invoke. But when working with lambdas and higher-order functions, it's often useful to be able to treat functions as polymorphic and interchangeable. The distinction between receivers and parameters is only cosmetic here, so Kotlin chooses to ignore it unless you make it explicit.

Comment: Side note: for all of the examples here, assume that the code appears inside a `main()` function. For reasons I'm unsure of, it looks like a function reference can only be invoked with a receiver if it's declared inside a function.

Answer (score 3):

> A function type with no receiver is inferred by default, even if a variable is initialized with a reference to an extension function.

I would reiterate it as (if it helps):

When a variable `x` is declared with no explicit type, is assigned a function with receiver `A.(B)->C` in its declaration — the inferred type of `x` is `(A,B)->C`, but not `A.(B)->C`.

Example:

```
fun Int.addThree(): Int = this + 3

//the type of x is inferred as `(Int)->Int`, not `Int.()->Int`
val x = Int::addThree

//"To alter that, specify the variable type explicitly"
val y: Int.()->Int = Int::addThree
```

We can test this with:

```
println(3.x()) //does not compile! (Unresolved reference: x)
println(3.y()) //ok
```

---

This documentation is placed where it is, because right above it is a section that explains how **"Non-literal values of function types with and without a receiver are interchangeable"**

```
//The value assigned to variable `a` — `::addTwo`,
//  is a function reference,
//  *NOT* a literal value of function type
fun addTwo(i: Int) = i + 2
val a = ::addTwo

//The value assigned to variable `b` — `AddTwo()`,
//  is an instance of a custom class that implements the function type as an interface,
//  *NOT* a literal value of function type
class AddTwo : (Int) -> Int {
    override fun invoke(i: Int): Int {
        return i + 2
    }
}
val b = AddTwo()

//The value assigned to variable `c` — `a`
//  is a variable of function type,
//  *NOT* a literal value of function type
val c = a

//The value assigned to variable `d` — `{ i:Int -> i + 2 }`,
//  is a lambda expression,
//  *IS* a literal value of function type
val d = { i:Int -> i + 2 }

//The value assigned to variable `e` — `fun(i: Int): Int { return i + 2 }`
//  is an anonymous function,
//  *IS* a literal value of function type
val e = fun(i: Int): Int { return i + 2 }
```

To demonstrate:

```
val a0: (Int)->Int = AddTwo()                          //OK
val b0: (Int)->Int = ::addTwo                          //OK
val c0: (Int)->Int = a                                 //OK
val d0: (Int)->Int = { i:Int -> i + 2 }                //OK
val e0: (Int)->Int = fun(i: Int): Int { return i + 2 } //OK

//"Non-literal values of function types with and without a receiver are interchangeable"
val a1: Int.()->Int = AddTwo()                          //OK
val b1: Int.()->Int = ::addTwo                          //OK
val c1: Int.()->Int = a                                 //OK
val d1: Int.()->Int = { i:Int -> i + 2 }                //ERROR: Expected no parameters
val e1: Int.()->Int = fun(i: Int): Int { return i + 2 } //ERROR: Expected no parameters
```